# Kotlin data class cannot init attribute of Parent class

Tags: kotlin, constructor, extends

like this:

```
open class Father(
        val name:String = ""
)

data class Son(
        val age:Int = 1
):Father()

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val son = Son(
            name = "",
            age = 10
    )
}
```

I cannot init "**name**" attribute of Son because of it is from Parent Class Father. 
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
open class Father(open val name: String="")

data class Son(val age: Int = 1,
override val name: String    ) : Father(name)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
val son = Son(name = "",age = 10)
}
```

Comment: but there's too many classes like 'Son', this way make so many duplicate code....

Comment: Why do you need to override `name` in `Son`?  It should work (more simply) without the `override val`, simply passing the parameter up to the superclass constructor.